# How to adapt font size to fill the viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to have a few lines of text filling up my viewport as much as possible. It does not have to be continuously adaptive (= it is OK to refresh when the viewport is changed, it does not need to adapt together with the viewport when its size changes interactively)

I tried [`FitText.js`](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js) and [`BigText`](https://github.com/zachleat/BigText) - they work great to compute a font size which will use the whole **width** of the viewport. If the **height** is too small then the text does not fit (scrollbars appear)

I tired to use [viewport-percentage lengths](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths) (specifically `vmin`) but while the size of the font adapts to the width, the value of `vmin` needs to be manually adapted to find the right width.

Is there a solution similar to `FitText` or `BigText`, but which would also take into account the height of the viewport?

Comment: There is an [enhancement PR](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js/pull/6/files) to `FitText.js` that hasn't been merged, but worth a try.

Comment: @Merott: I just downloaded `example.html` and the modified `jquery.fittext.js` which are indeed advertised to do exactly what I am looking for. I get a transformation of the size for the width, but still not for the height (when resizing the browser vertically the font size does not change and eventually scroll bars appear)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider a pure css approach:

```
.textcontainer{
    font-size: 12px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){

    .textcontainer{
        font-size: 14px;
    }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px){
    .textcontainer{
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say that this wasn't the exact thing OP was asking. The solution should cover something that scales the font size automatically to fill the space available for it. Media queries are however a really good solution if it is doable and easily doable in OP's case to adjust the font-size manually.

Comment: Thanks but this essentially fixes the size of the font for specific screen sizes. There is no adaptation to the size (except for listing all possible sizes and choosing a font size for each)

Comment: @WoJ Maybe if you use **em** instead of **px**, you could get the expected result

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoB.Carucce: what I am trying to say is that the adaptation is only for fixed, predefined sizes of the screen. This will not work if my browser size is `318x937`, then `1011x48`. I would need to basically build one entry for each expected size.